# Angular production build files over https

Tags: angular, http, https

when I use ng serve in angular cli to serve my angular app everything is OK, my files: polyfill.js, styles.js, favicon.ico are served over http. However, when I do ng build --prod and serve that files over some http server,  polyfill.js, styles.js, favicon.ico are requested over https, and since this is local server without https, loading fails.
I am using Angular: 11.0.4.
I have similar project built two years ago with I think angular 9, and I am using the same http server, just on different machine, and it is working as expected (no https).
What is the problem here?

[image]

Comment: Are you building on the root site directory, or are the files accessed from a subpath?

Comment: The files are in dist folder

Comment: Not what I meant. Do you access it from a virtual folder? or the root domain?

Comment: from root domain... I have event tried from express:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
//Serve angular app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

Comment: have you change the base path while building the project or directly in the file. `ng build --base-href="/demos/"`

Comment: I have not change the base path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Content-Security-Policy header that forced https...realize this when I tried simple http-server form npm...

Comment: Is there any flag available for http-server to disable this in local-development ?

Comment: I think flr http-server it is disabled by default